# Github commit message links

Tags: git, github

Is it possible to create a commit message with link to other repository commit?

Eg. something like `[Username\Repo\commitHash]`

Usage example: *if some bc break would happen in some framework's commit, I'd like to link to this very commit in my own commits updating my code which uses this framework.*

Comment: You accepted the wrong answer bud...

Comment: @RobinWinslow I'm pretty sure it was accurate back then. Anyway, you are right it would be appropriate to update it. Done.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

I was searching for something like this myself. Found it on:

https://help.github.com/articles/autolinked-references-and-urls/#commit-shas

```
<<username>>/<<repo>>@<<commitHash>>
```

Without the angle brackets of course :)

Comment: Thanks. I've tried it, but it seems like the hash always points to `current-repo/commits/the-hash` path, no matter what is in front of it. But at least we can use the commit hash to link to current repository.

Comment: Are you certain this is the case? I just did write antitoxic/diem@2b4514646177a95951202c4aea388cf472b53ca1 in github issues and it is displayed as link correctly.

Comment: Yup, and if you're within the project you can just do `@COMMIT_HASH`.

Comment: You don't even need the `@`. `COMMIT_HASH` is sufficient.

Comment: key thing to remember: @ for commit hash, # for issue

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's anything stopping you from putting something like:

http://github.com/pkrumins/lulzbot/commit/4c1b1ea95b379805e3b595b511a89affc6811145

Right in your commit message. While this doesn't link directly to the git object's version of the commit... it leads to a page showing that commit.

Format is github.com/User/Repo/commit/hashtag

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think this is the right way to do this (even if it is the only way). As with the `close #issue_number` tag, I'd expect something similar.