# Git (assembla) - Syntax to refer to a previous changeset in a commit message

Tags: git, version-control, commit, assembla

Does git have any official syntax that can be inserted into commit messages to reference previous changesets? E.g.:

```
Oops. Adding files accidentally missed out from #7557bd82e2d0c7335319392b4bcb178ce0b9620f
```

Or does Git not bother defining these, and leaves that up to the tool that is used to display the messages (e.g. [Github](https://github.com/) or [Assembla](https://www.assembla.com))?

In which case, does anyone know if Assembla has any such syntax, hopefully to convert the reference into a link to that changeset? If GitHub has syntax for this then Assembla probably copied them...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Git, there is no such thing as "previous commit". There is a previous commit at a given point, but after a merge, a new commit might come to the branch and be inserted between "current commit" and "previous commit".

However, Assembla *can* link to a specific commit in git changeset logs. If you know the exact sha or HEAD you want to link to, you can use Assembla's markup:

Here are some examples:

```
[[r:c27dbd5d84dfa9302c47a26196221c921c7d8c12|link to sha]]
[[r:c27dbd5d84dfa9302c47a26196221c921c7d8c12]]
[[url:www.assembla.com/code/<:space>/git/nodes/master|link to head]]
```

Here are those examples in action: https://www.assembla.com/code/bobo-titas/git/nodes/867b914329

More information about Assembla's linking can be found in the "create new wiki page" page.

Comment: oops sorry it took me so long to accept. This was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: I can't seem to get this to work with multiple repos. I've seen someone mention that you could use a format like [[r:<changeset id>:git-2]] to specify the changeset, but when I do this it won't even convert the markup to a link.

Answer (score 1):

There is no predefined markup to specify commit hashes.

Git commit hashes are just hexadecimal numbers, so I guess you just do regex matching of `/\<[0-9a-fA-f]{4,40}\>/` (minimum 4 digits, maximum 40 digits). You could additionally check if the match is a valid Git object (`git rev-parse --verify "$match"`).

---

Seems like GitHub does have a special syntax after all. To specify commits in other repositories use the format `<<username>>/<<repo>>@<<commitHash>>` (details can be found in the question [Github commit message links](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4884507/112968)).
Although I would personally avoid direct cross-project commit references.

Comment: In Github there is syntax for this (see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3832227/github-commit-message-links#comment16590363_3832227) but this doesn't seem to work in Assembla. Perhaps you could add this into your answer?